# Getting Facebook event image using the facebook sdk for .Net with the graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

When I try to execute:

```
      dynamic picture = fb.Get(string.Format("{0}/picture",id.ToString())); //("event-id/picture")
```

I get JsonReaderException - "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Line 1, position 1." at

```
      obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type, SerializerSettings);
```

What wrong with my request?

Thanks in advance,
Alon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving pictures through the graph for profiles and events the graph url will resolve into the image url. You don't need to query the graph.
This will get you the picture for an event (try it in your browser!):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{eventid}/picture
```